# Clearfix isn't working (or it's my fault). Elements on bottom overflow the container

Tags: html, css

I [have this site](http://kuki.im/tootoo/new_class.html) and as you can see at the bottom the letters and the hr line overflowing the container. I tried to apply a clearfix but it's not working. I've added an `overflow: hidden` on container class but as I know this is not the best way to achieve that. One "dirty" solution is to add to the last element of the page `margin-bottom` but i want a more cleaner way. What I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `.wrap`'s `top: 19px` is causing it. <strike>Switching that to `margin-top: 19px` (or even dropping it) fixes it. Just check if you need to modify some other rules to get your original design back (check the very top part of the page).</strike>

To keep the original look, use `padding-top: 19px` instead of it.

Comment: that did it! I've added `padding-top` to the container and now everything is ok! Thank you